What session is running a decryption of my database?
I have a very nice query that tells me when the decryption of my database has finished.
SELECT 
    DB_NAME(database_id) DbName,
    EncryptState = CASE encryption_state  
                       WHEN 0 THEN '0- No database encryption key present, no encryption'
                       WHEN 1 THEN '1 = Unencrypted'
                       WHEN 2 THEN '2 = Encryption in progress'
                       WHEN 3 THEN '3 = Encrypted'
                       WHEN 4 THEN '4 = Key change in progress'
                       WHEN 5 THEN '5 = Decryption in progress'
                       WHEN 6 THEN '6 = Protection change in progress (The certificate or asymmetric key that is encrypting the database encryption key is being changed.)'
                       ELSE 'chant hare krishna and be happy!'
                   END,
    percent_complete,
    key_algorithm KeyAlgorithm,
    key_length KeyLength,
    encryptor_type EncryptType, *
FROM 
    sys.dm_database_encryption_keys WITH(NOLOCK)

How can I identify which session is doing the decryption? Is it possible at all?
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions s

would check for DROP DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY inside the text of the request associated with that session be a good option?
